# Yoneda lemma for enriched categories

Tags: category-theory, enriched-category-theory

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a monoidal category. Is there a generalization of the Yoneda lemma to categories enriched over $\mathcal{M}$?

In the specific case I need, $\mathcal{M}$ would be the category $k\operatorname{-Vect}$ of $k$-vector spaces.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+Yoneda+lemma).

Comment: @Pece That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Would you like to summarize the statement and give the link in an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, see [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+Yoneda+lemma). A standard reference is Kelly's *Basic concepts of enriched category theory*, [TAC reprint](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html). The case of $k$-linear categories is very simple (basically because here the monoidal unit is a generator). Here, $k$ can be any commutative ring. For $k$-linear functors $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Mod}_k$ and objects $A \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ there is a canonical $k$-linear map
$$\mathrm{Hom}\bigl(\mathrm{Hom}(A,-),F\bigr) \to F(A)$$
which is an isomorphism since by the usual Yoneda Lemma the underlying map of sets is an isomorphism.

Comment: You should indicate that this generalization is to enrichments in (monoidal) *closed* categories (unless I'm mistaken and there is a way to generalize the Yoneda lemma for enrichments in non-closed monoidal categories, but I don't think I am and would love a reference); in particular the correct answer to the question asked would be "No, unless the monoidal category is closed, in which case yes".

Comment: What do you know, a reference was published 4 days after I left the comment... http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/31/29/31-29abs.html